# Wrapping a wrapper of console log with correct file/line number?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I found a way to wrap `console.log` so that when called through the wrapper it preserves the file/line number from where it was called.

But I'd like to know how I could wrap it once more (perhaps several times if the actual `logging` happened to be in a very deep level).

```js
class Debugger {
  _log() {
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
  }

  log = this._log();

  specialLog(msg: string) {
    this.log('special: ' + msg);
  }
}

const debug = new Debugger();
debug.log('hi'); // works perfect: correct file/line number
debug.specialLog('hi'); // line number -> where this.log() is called.
```

From this sample code, how should I modify `specialLog` so that it works as `log`?
I've tried several combinations with `.bind`, `.apply`, `.call` trying to pass the `console` context through, but no success.

update:

```js
specialLog(msg: string) {
  return this.log.bind(console, 'special ' + msg);
}

debug.specialLog('hi')(); // correct, but notice the extra '()'
```

This is the closest I could get, but is there a way to do it without having to execute it after call?

update 2: jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mqa1duvr/

update 3: reason I need it to go through another wrapper:
The actual debugger looks something like this:

```js
class Debugger {
  debug(...)
  trace(...)
  // and inside each these debug..trace..warn etc..
  // there are set colors, timestamps, send log to server etc..
  // then, finally after all the filters, there's the "final" log.
  _log(...)
}
```

If I can make it go through several functions deep while having the caller's context, then I could keep the functions small.

Comment: I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`. Sure this is valid JS?

Comment: sorry, I'll add the typescript tag

Comment: About the update, use `call` instead of `bind`.

Comment: `this.log.call(console, 'special ' + msg);` using call works but with wrong line number. It points to the line where `.call` is made. instead, it should point to `debug.specialLog('hi')`

Comment: Well the problem is that the line number is associated with the call to `console.log`. It just prints whatever line that call was made.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir hi, please post your answer again, I made it work with `specialLog = Function.prototype.bind.call(this.log, console, 'special:');` using `this.log` instead of `console.log` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default arguments (the string `"special: "`) using `bind`. So this should work:

```
specialLog =  Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console, "Special: ");
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Explanation:**

When `specialLog` get called, the first argument passed to `console.log` will always be `"Special: "`, so if you call it like:

```
specialLog("Hello, world!");
```

it will be as if you call `console.log` like:

```
console.log("Special: ", "Hello, world!");
```

which prints the string: `"Special: Hello, world!"`, your desired result.

user7552 (op) edit:
for my case, it would be:

```
specialLog =  Function.prototype.bind.call(this.log, console, "Special:");
```

using `this.log` (reference inside the debugger class), instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please check update 3. why I need it to go through another wrapper.