# How to bind console.log to another function call so I can see line number of the script in console where it is called?

Tags: javascript

My code works but with additional parenthesis like `myfunction()();`. It should execute with single parenthesis just like normal e.g `myfunction();`.

I'm building `console.time(); console.timeEnd();` polyfill for browsers (e.g <IE10) which do not have native built-in. Note: I have bind() polyfill in-case you think <IE10 does not have it.

Here is my code in "polyfill.js file".

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var console=window.console,  timers={};
    
    if (!console.time) {
        
        console.time = function(name) {
            var datenow = Date.now();
            name = name? name: 'default';
            if (timers[name]) {
                console.warn('Timer "'+name+'" already exists.');
            }
            else timers[name] = datenow;
        };
        
        console.timeEnd = function(name) {
            var datenow = Date.now();
            name = name? name: 'default';
            if (!timers[name]) {
                console.warn('Timer "'+name+'" does not exists.');
            }
            else {
                var endt = datenow - timers[name];
                delete timers[name];
                //below is the line where some changes are needed, But I don't know how.
                return window.console.log.bind(window.console, name+ ': ' +endt+ 'ms');
            }
        };
    }
}());
```

Now in another file "main.js file",  when I use `console.time(); console.timeEnd();`,  it should log code-line-number of this file in browser console (not the line-number of polyfill.js file). Of-course it works but notice additional parenthesis "()()" below which is not cool.

```
console.time();
//any code for performance test goes here.
console.timeEnd()(); //Note here "()()". It should be single "()"
```

I have consulted these 2 stackoverflow questions, but couldn't come up with the right answer.

- [Wrapping a wrapper of console log with correct file/line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254277/wrapping-a-wrapper-of-console-log-with-correct-file-line-number)
- [A proper wrapper for console.log with correct line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815640/a-proper-wrapper-for-console-log-with-correct-line-number/32928812)

I also checked `new Error().stack;` as an option, but it is also not supported in those browser for which I'm building my polyfill.

**Note:** If anyone can suggest a solution with `eval();`, you can. It is also acceptable for me.

Comment: So, is the problem that `console.log` will show the filename and line number of the location it was *called* from? Because if that's the case, then I don't see how what you want to achieve is possible. A getter could be a solution but I guess those browser don't support getters either.

Comment: @FelixKling I couldn't understand what you mean. What I want is just `console.timeEnd()();` should execute with single parenthesis like `console.timeEnd();`

Comment: If you would not use a stone age browser you could also use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: @TheFool , I want to support all old browsers. Those browsers still have some user-base. I don't want to miss them.

Comment: Define all old browser. Like IE1 too? Also, Netscape maybe?

Comment: @TheFool, hahaha, no brother. I want to support IE6-11, opera-mini & old opera browsers etc.

Comment: Change `return window.console.log.bind(window.console, name+ ': ' +endt+ 'ms');` to `return window.console.log(name+ ': ' +endt+ 'ms');` so you're invoking the log function instead of returning a new bound function.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal , if I do so what you suggested, it will log the line-number of polyfill.js file.  But I want it to log the line-number of "main.js file"

Comment: I see, you have three requirements: 1. support old browsers, 2. log the line number where the call was made, and 3. avoid the double brackets `()()`. Unfortunately, for technical reasons, it's not possible to have all three at once, you'll have to compromise on one of them. Either: A. allow `()()` and use your polyfill as-is (✅1, ✅2, ❌3); B. drop support for old browsers and use the `getter` to avoid `()()` (❌1, ✅2, ✅3); C. or don't use `console.log.bind` to avoid `()()` but lose the line number (✅1, ❌2, ✅3).

Comment: @Sly_cardinal , can you give me solution with "getter". I can later use polyfill for getter if a browser don't have support for it. thank you.

Comment: It's the updated answer in the link you have in your question: "A proper wrapper for console.log with correct line numver": https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415531/81723 Getters and `Object.defineProperty()` are only supported down to IE9, it's not possible to polyfill them in earlier browsers. But I think using getters is the best approach given your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact a function for that called `console.trace`, which you can read more about in the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/trace).
What it does is print the entire stack trace to the line where it has been called from.

So, for example, running the next code:

```
function firstFunc() {
  secondFunc();
}

function secondFunc() {
  console.trace('I was called here!');
}

console.log('Calling firstFunc:');
firstFunc();
```

will print out this output in the console:

```
Calling firstFunc:

I was called here!
secondFunc @ VM141:6
firstFunc @ VM141:2
(anonymous) @ VM141:10 // Internal browser trace
```

Notice that in the given output, all functions are being called and defined in the Chrome console, hence the `@ VM141:`. Generally, it prints the file instead of VM. So, had it been located in an `index.js` file, it would look like this:

```
Calling firstFunc:

I was called here!
secondFunc @ index.js:8
```

**Compatibility Note**

The above method works for any sane browser, and IE11+. That is due to the implementation of `console.trace` only in IE11.
However, per OP's request, I can think of a creative way to support IE10, and that is by using the [`Error.prototype.stack` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack).
Now, of course, as MDN itself mentions it, it's a non-standard feature that should not be used in production, but neither is supporting IE6.

By creating an Error instance and then printing its stack, you can achieve a similar result.

```
const sumWithTrace = (num1, num2) => {
  console.log(new Error().stack); // Creating a new error for its stack property
  return num1 + num2;
};

sumWithTrace(1, 5); // returns 6 and prints trace in console
```

Comment: IE9 is telling me, `console.trace();` "Object doesn't support property or method 'trace'"

Comment: why are you using IE9 ?

Comment: First of all, I agree with @TheFool, but it makes sense: In the MDN doc that I linked it clearly shows in the compatibility table that `console.trace` is supported only in IE11 and above.

Comment: I want to support all old browsers.

Comment: First of all, I doubt any of your users need to see a trace log in their console. I suppose this is purely for development, where you probably use far more up-to-date browsers. Second of all, the world-wide usage, and even the usage among all Internet Explorers and Edge browsers, of IE10 and below is under 1%.

Comment: @samar edited to my best effort

Comment: right now I'm playing with `new Error().stack` I will come back to your answer if I could come up with what I want. I am very grateful for your effort. thank you. I will also wait in-case some other user come up with a different idea.

Comment: By the way, is your only problem the fact that you need to call the timeEnd twice, or do you try to find a way to print the line number regardless? @samar

Comment: @EldarB. my only only problem is with calling the `timeEnd()()` twice. It should work with one call like `timeEnd()`.

Comment: @samar Then I just added an answer that solves that problem. I thought your main concern was printing the line.

Comment: @EldarB. , A solution with `eval();`, is also acceptable for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237521/discussion-between-eldar-b-and-samar).